# Logic error in drawing a continuous line in processing

Tags: java, logic, processing

I'm trying to draw a continuous line in processing using previous lines drawn and generating a new line segment every frame.

I have an `ArrayList` called lines and every time a new line is generatied, the `x` and `y` positions of the start and end of the line is added to the `ArrayList`.

I then, in a display function loops through the `ArrayList` and for every item in it draw a new line, however my code below draws a single smaller line (the one that's just been created) and nothing else.

My code for drawing the line looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t.lines.size()-1; i++) {
  println(i);
  line(lines.get(i)[0],lines.get(i)[1], lines.get(i)[2], lines.get(i)[3]);
}
```

and my code for makeing a new line adn adding the coordinates is this:

```
xi += 0.01;
x = xl;
xl = x + xi;
yl = y;

line[0] = x;
line[1] = y;
line[2] = xl;
line[3] = yl;

lines.add(line);`
```

As I said, I would like to be able to draew a continuous line with this and will be chaning y coordinates once i have ironed this problem out. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Could you post your line method code ?

Comment: @benjamin.d what's my line method code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily solve your problem if you just take the "end coordinates" from the first line as the "start coordinates" of the second line and so on.